# Print error message if no results have been found using find

Tags: bash, shell, unix, xargs

I am attempting to write a bash script that prints all files in path $1 which have been modified later than $2. Here's my script:

```
find ./$1 -mtime -$2 -type f | xargs du -h | sort
```

Now, if the script does not return any results, I want it to print an error message such as "No such files found". How can I print a message if, and only if, no filenames have been found & printed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can store the result and check if the variable has content or not; if not, print this error; if it does, print the output: `[ -z "$result" ] && echo "nothing found" || echo "$result"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
#!/bin/bash

# create a temp file
tmp=$(mktemp)

# run find and redirect output to temp file
find ./"$1" -mtime -"$2" -type f > "$tmp"

# check if temp file is not empty 
if [[ -s "$tmp" ]]; then
    cat "$tmp"
else
    echo "No such files found"
fi

# delete temp file
rm "$tmp"
```

Comment: We can store whole output in a local variable and check that for printing actual result vs printing `No such files found`.

Comment: Would it not be better to store it in a file ?

Comment: True I agree using temporary file will be better than local variables.